# Splitting a big query in Oracle

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, timeout

I've got a big query which gives me a timeout. I don't want to configure the Database configurations so my Idea is to split the query into smaller.

Is it possible to iterate (for example: over `500 Data sets`), put it in a loop and then Update always 500 Data Sets till the Table count?

If so, suggestions how to code it?

My SQL Executioner:

```
If Connection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
    myCMD = New OracleCommand(sSQL, Connection)
            myCMD.CommandTimeout = 30
            myReader = myCMD.ExecuteReader()
    While myReader.Read
      Dim row = New ArrayList
      For i = 0 To myReader.FieldCount - 1
        row.Add(myReader(i))
      Next
      resultSet.Add(row)
    End While
    myReader.Close()
```

Comment: It seems like a batch job. Why not implement it as an stored procedure and avoid data traffic from ddbb to app?

Comment: @Oscar how is calling a stored procedure solving my problem with the timeout? (Sorry, i'm not very good in SQL/Databases)

Comment: Not having to move large amounts of data from ddbb to app is a good improvement.

Comment: Where is it timing out? If it's the select query, then you could try putting index, optimizing your query to make it faster or add where clause to do (for example) one category at a time. Make sure you return only what is needed. Based on your While loop, why not just add everything in a dataset instead of putting it in a list of list?